# Poisson regression for time series data?

Tags: r, bayesian, count-data, poisson-regression

I collected citation data on four scholars for two time-points. For this I
selected different types of literature (journal articles, encyclopedias, etc.).
I would therefore state, that the data I have are a sample. The data is as
follows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rstanarm)

my_dat <- tribble(~year, ~person, ~n,
                  "1970", "A", 102,
                  "2010", "A", 80,
                  "1970", "B", 138,
                  "2010", "B", 128,
                  "1970", "C", 158,
                  "2010", "C", 81,
                  "1970", "D", 174,
                  "2010", "D", 202)
my_dat
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>    year person     n
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1  1970      A   102
#> 2  2010      A    80
#> 3  1970      B   138
#> 4  2010      B   128
#> 5  1970      C   158
#> 6  2010      C    81
#> 7  1970      D   174
#> 8  2010      D   202
```

Now I would like to assess with what plausibility I could state, that each of
those scholars either was more important in 2010 or less important, measured by 
citation counts. Since the data come from a sample, I don't want to simply
plot the points with lines and state: "Scholar B is a bit less relevant, since
the citation count decreased." I'd like to make a statement like this: "Given
the data (and the model, see below), we can be very confident that scholar C was
cited less often, and quite confident that scholar D was cited more often."

I thought, I could model these data with a poisson regression like the following:

```r
mod1 <- stan_glm(n ~ 0 + year:person, data = my_dat,
                 family = poisson, prior = normal(0, 2.5))
#> trying deprecated constructor; please alert package maintainer
```

I would sample from the posterior and plot it like this.

[image]

But I suspect, I could be completely wrong in what I'm doing:

- I'm not taking into account, that the data come from a time series.
- I'm not sure, if those 8 data-points warrant a model like this, and whether or
  not the specification without intercept creates problems on its own.

If I'm completely off with this approach: how could I measure/display the
uncertainty in the direction and magnitude of the change frome 1970 to 2010?

Comment: Hyperbolic, to make the point clear that Stephan also makes below and provoke some thinking, you can be very confident that scholar C was cited less often than scholar D, because you counted the citations. Your uncertainty doesn't really apply to the counts of citations, at least you can be certain that the number of citations in 1970 for C was not less than 150, because you've counted at least 150 of them.

Comment: @Gijs Your second point is very obvious, and I missed that, so the display above doesn't make a lot of sense. Comparing two scholars however, I think I cannot be certain about their order with my data alone, since if I'd chosen different journals to sample, the data could be different.

Comment: Yes, there is uncertainty. But it's not really like you took a random sample of journals and are approximating a true underlying "citation rate" per journal per year. I think statistical tests are a bit problematic here. At least, a poisson regression is a bit too crude a model it seems for how these numbers appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the time series aspect into account, since you are modeling that certain data points come from the same persons. If you have only two data points per person, an AR or similar model doesn't make a lot of sense.

Your presentation of uncertainty is also nice.

I'm more concerned about the fact that you are running a Bayesian model with eight parameters and eight data points. I'd expect your results to heavily depend on the priors. Have you varied the priors to see what influence they have?

You should be able to get more citation counts than for just two years (that are 40 years apart). If you could get more data, you could probably do more sophisticated modeling.

And I'm not so sure whether your data are just a *sample*. Yes, of course it is a sample of the base population of "all researchers". But if you are only interested in your four specific researchers, then whether or not your data are "just a sample" depends on whether there are citations to these people's work that are not captured in your citation counts. And while Google Scholar and similar are imprecise in counting citations, I'd still think they are 90% correct, so the difference between your data and the base population (all citations to A-D) is pretty small. In which case, it isn't very helpful to do a whole lot of statistical inference. Best to just report the raw numbers.

Comment: I'm using this approach, since we explicitly didn't use google scholar: for the two time-points we hand coded data from: 5 journals, textbooks, handbooks and one encyclopedia. Therefore the counts I have are a sample regarding all citations those four scholars got in those years.

Comment: The prior has a strong influence on the location of the posterior, but I'm not very much concerned with the absolute values of the parameters. The variability in estimates seems to come solely from the likelihood, not being affected by the prior. The question is then probably, whether the use of a Poisson distribution for the likelihood is adequate here.